# What is the extent of variable visibility effect of synchronized/volatile in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, volatile

According to "Java Concurrency in Practice":

> ***everything*** A did in or prior to a synchronized block is visible to B when it executes a synchronized block guarded by the same lock

and

> The visibility effects of volatile variables extend beyond the value of the volatile variable itself. When thread A writes to a volatile variable and subsequently thread B reads that same variable, the values of ***all variables*** that were visible to A prior to writing to the volatile variable become visible to B after reading the volatile variable

what I'm not clear about is what dose it mean by ***everything*** and ***all variables***? Dose it mean everything literally? If we have a class like this:

```
class MyClassA{
  int a;
  int[] array = new int[10];
  MyClassB myClass; // a class with similar properties

  void notSyncronizedMethod(){
      // do something with a, array[3], myClass.a, myClass.array[3]
  }
  syncronized void syncronizedMethodA(){
      // update value of a, array[3], myClass.a, myClass.array[3]
  }
  syncronized void syncronizedMethodB(){
      // do something with a, array[3], myClass.a, myClass.array[3]
  }
}
```

if we call `syncronizedMethodA()` in one thread and then call `syncronizedMethodB()` or `notSyncronizedMethod()` in another thread, assume the time order is stritly garanteed, will call of `syncronizedMethodB()` and `notSyncronizedMethod()` use the latest variable value set by `syncronizedMethodA()`. I'm sure value of a is OK for `syncronizedMethodB()`, but what about elements of reference types like array[3], myClass.a or even myClass.myClass.array[3]? What about `notSyncronizedMethod()` with value updated by an syncronized method?

Comment: Re, "does it mean everything literally?" Yes. If thread A updates a variable (_any_ variable) before it releases some lock, then from thread B's point of view, that update is guaranteed to have "happened before" thread B locks the same lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to figure out what visibility guarantees are provided, you need to understand the Java Memory Model a little better, and more specifically, what happens-before means in the context of the JMM. The JMM describes things that happen as *actions*, for example, normal reads and writes, volatile reads and writes, lock, unlock, etc.

There are a handful of [rules](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-multi-threading/happens-before.html) in the JMM that establish when one action happens-before another action. The rules relevant in your case are the following:

The *single thread rule*: in a given thread, action A happens-before action B if A precedes B in program order.

The *monitor lock rule* (synchronized): An unlock of given monitor happens-before a subsequent lock on the same monitor.

It's important to know that *happens-before* is transitive, i.e. if hb(a, b) and hb(b, c), then hb(a, c).

In your example, one thread releases the monitor when exiting `syncronizedMethodA()`, and another thread subsequently acquires the monitor when entering `syncronizedMethodB()`. That's one happens-before relation. And since HB is transitive, actions performed in `syncronizedMethodA()` become visible for any thread that subsequently enters `syncronizedMethodB()`.

On the other hand, no happens-before relation exists between the release of the monitor in `syncronizedMethodA()` and subsequent actions performed in `notSynchronizedMethod()` by another thread. Therefore, there are no guarantees that the writes in `syncronizedMethodA()` are made visible to another thread's reads in `notSynchronizedMethod()`.